# Command works in script (or -c), but not when ran directly (in an interactive shell)

Tags: shell

This works:

```
$ bash -c 'while true; do echo foo; sleep 1; done'
foo
foo
...
```

But not this:

```
$ while true; do echo foo; sleep 1; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

I see same issue with zsh:

> zsh: parse error near `done'

NOTE: dash works.

Comment: There is no difference. What is your problem?

Comment: Both works in my bash 4.4.23 without any problem. What's the exact error message on your system?
And is your running shell realy bash?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to show the issue

Comment: What bash version is this? If you have the same issue with `zsh` I guess that at least one of the characters differs from what you presented here. So type this command again and check again

Comment: This is Debian, bash=5.5.1-1+b1 zsh=4.4.18-3.1

Comment: Did you try to use cut/paste from the text in this question?

Comment: Yeah, same issue @schily

Comment: then I recommend you to make a bug report against Debian. bash-5.0 (self compiled) and zsh-5.1.1 (from Ubuntu) behave correctly. BTW: do you have any strange aliases?

Comment: Damn, it's the alias (`alias do='docker'`), silly me!

Comment: I mixed versions of bash and zsh in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464780/shell-code-works-in-script-but-not-when-ran-directly/464788#comment846066_464780)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem like this are frequently missunderstood as few people realize that `aliases` are disabled in non-interactive shells.

In your case it was an alias named `do` that caused the problem.

To investigate in similar problems, it usually helps to start a new shell with:

```
HOME=/tmp $shell
```

and try again. This avoids that the interactive shell reads startup scripts.